# TableView inside horizontal scrollview not accepting row action gesture

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

`UIScrollView`->`UIEmbedView`->`UITableView`->`UIRowAction`

Row action only works when scroll is disabled. Is there a trick to passing the drag gesture or prioritizing gestures?

Comment: A table view is already a `UIScrollView`. Why is your table embedded in another scroll view?

Comment: A horizontal scrollview. Left side is navigation (hamburger-esk) right side is main content view.

Comment: @Justin How do you want to make it? I mean, there obviously is a gestures conflict. The same gesture – the horizontal swipe (pan) – is used for scrolling at `UIScrollView` and for triggering the `UIRowAction`. So you need to separate them somehow. By the action zone for example. Do you want row actions being called when gesture was started near the edge of the screen or maybe else somehow?